# Django registration login redirection

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, django-registration, django-1.5

With django-registration, I have in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

When I'm trying to access a page (signed out) like `http://localhost:8000/surfboards/current/`, I'm redirected to `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/surfboards/current/`

In that case, if the `next` parameter is specified, I'd like to be after login successfully redirected to this page, and not to the default `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

For now, I'm always redirected to `http://localhost:8000/`, which is what I want only if `next` isn't specified.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

django login view is internally used by django-registration for login. And `login` view provided by django takes care of `next`.

I guess you are missing sending it from the template.

Do you have following line in `registration/login.html`?

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{next}}">
```

If not, then add it, and your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Perfect, easy and fast, thanks a lot! I just added `type="hidden" `for this input field and it works great

Comment: Yeah, I should have added `type="hidden"` :)

Comment: Thanks! Now I can redirect to an URL like /profiles/home. Would you know how I can redirect to something like /profiles/home/nn where nn is the  user ID?
And, BTW, what is the value of {{next}} anyway?